CRON syntax on a specific day
I am trying to create a cron on this rule :
The 15th of each month but if it is the week end launch it the next monday
The cron below is near what I want, but it take the nearest work day. If the 15 is on a saturday it take the friday. I want the monday.
0 0 12 15W * ?

Is there something I missed ?
